# Powershell 2.0 Format-list output to JSON?

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-2.0

```
PS B:\abrabackups> . C:\ps\ConvertTo-JSON.ps1
PS B:\abrabackups> Get-ItemProperty -Path .\AbraSuite01.03.2014 | select Name,CreationTime | ConvertTo-JSON
```

And that gives me: *(formatted for clarity)*

```
{
 "CreationTime": "2014-01-03T16:48:36", 
 "Name": "AbraSuite01.03.2014"
}
```

Well that's all well and good, but suppose I want my dates in a different format in the JSON string, is there anyway to do this in powershell and still use my [shoehorned ConvertTo-JSON.ps1 for powershell 2.0?](https://gist.github.com/mdnmdn/6936714)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert your dates to the format you want before converting to JSON by using a [calculated property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx). For example:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path .\AbraSuite01.03.2014 | select Name,@{Name="CreationTime";Expression={$_.CreationTime.ToShortDateString()}} | ConvertTo-JSON
```

Replace `$_.CreationTime.ToShortDateString()` with whatever you need to get the date format you're after - but the key here is to use `$_.CreationTime` to grab the creation time of the object in the pipeline.

Comment: What is the `@{...}` syntax called?

Comment: In this context, it's called a [calculated property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx).