# Can calculated properties in Powershell be refactored into a Function?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

For instance, I have several date attributes I'd like to retrieve from a single folder.  I'd like to format them in a particular format.  I've found a way to do this using `Get-Date` inside of a [calculated property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156504/powershell-2-0-format-list-output-to-json#comment-33625336).

```
PS B:\abrabackups> Get-ItemProperty -Path .\AbraSuite01.03.2014 | select Name,@{Name="CreationTime";Expression={($_.CreationTime | Get-Date -format 'ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss') + ' GMT-000' }} | ConvertTo-JSON
```

However, if I do this for the rest of the date attributes I have to copy and paste the expression of the calculated property several times over:

```
@{Name=$some_date_attr;Expression={($_.$some_date_attr | Get-Date -format 'ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss') + ' GMT-000' }}
```

If anything changes in the format I have to change it as many times are there are date properties.  Is there a way to refactor it into a function that I can pass a date attribute to and have the function return it in the requested format?

Comment: By the way, why do you have braces around the value of `Expression`? I'm not sure what that does if it doesn't throw a syntax error.

Comment: The `Expression` is a code block and therefore should be wrapped in braces. See [this Technet article with examples](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basic programming. All you do is create a function with an input and have it return a value. I am going to assume that the data type of the date value is a `DateTime` or castable as one.

```
function MyDateFormat([DateTime]$date) {
    return (Get-Date $date -format 'ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss') + ' GMT-000'
}
```

(Please choose a better name, of course. This is only an example.) Then call your function instead:

```
@{Name=$some_date_attr;Expression=(MyDateFormat $_.some_date_attr)}
```

If you really want it in GMT, you may want to make sure it's actually using a [UTC time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
Function Format-Date{
    Param([DateTime]$InputDate)
    (Get-Date $InputDate -format 'ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss') + ' GMT-000'
}
```

Then just throw a date object at that, or a string in a date format ("1/13/14" or "2/14/14 21:12:47") and it spits back your desired format. You could name the function something shorter for ease of use of coarse.